# ListView only shows first item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to display all items of an `ArrayList<String>` on a `ListView`. I use an `ArrayAdapter<String>` for this. The problem is that only the first item ('foo' in my example) of the `ArrayList` is shown. Can someone tell me why? Am I missing something?

I've made an minimal example using the generated code (Tabbed Action Bar Spinner Activity) from Android Studio 2.

My `FooActivity`:

```
public class FooActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ...

 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView fooListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);

        fooListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.foo_list);
        updateList();
        return rootView;
     }

     private void updateList() {
            ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            strings.add("foo");
            strings.add("bar");

            if (mAdapter == null) {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
                        R.layout.item_foo,
                        R.id.foo_string,
                        strings);
                fooListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
                mAdapter.clear();
                mAdapter.addAll(strings);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
     }
}
```

My `fragment_foo.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.foo.activities.FooActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/foo_list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/total_activities"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `item_foo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some_string"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If it helps I can post the generated `activity_foo.xml` (I didn't made any changes there) and the complete `FooActivity` class too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Problem actually was my `activity_foo.xml` which had a `NestedScrollView`. I've added `android:fillViewport="true"` and now it shows every item.

My `NestedScrollView` now looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

On any `ListView`, if you use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, you're only going to see one item.  Try `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.  If the `ListView` only takes up part of the layout, you'll need a `LinearLayout` with weights or a `RelativeLayout` with constraints.  But `wrap_content` won't work for a height on a `ListView`, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Your Listview look something like this

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/foo_list"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

I have removed from your list view `android:layout_below="@+id/total_activities"`

and

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

For others: It's okay to nest a ListView inside another layout, and it's also fine to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on Layouts surrounding the ListView. (So long as the outer-most Layout allows for match_parent)

What is not fine, however, is when the TextView being used to populate the ListView is defined with `layout_height="match_parent"`. It will cover up all of the subsequent rows after the first.

Bad:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoRow_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Good:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoRow_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```